# Como poner de fondo de ventana un gif y qué este tenga movimiento?

Tags: java, jframe

Saludos, estoy intentando hacer lo que el encabezo dice, pero no sé como podría hacerlo...
Puse imágenes de fondo anteriormente y todo salio bien, pero el gif que pongo solo a veces sale y cuando no sale, no hay movimiento.

```
  public class Juego {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Ventana v = new Ventana();



}

}

public class Ventana extends JFrame{

public Ventana(){

    super("El laberinto");//Establece el nombre de la ventana
    setSize(700, 700);//Establece el tamaño
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//Establece una operacion por deafaul al cerrar
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Hace que la pantalla no pueda manipularse de tamaño
    setVisible(true);
    //setResizable(false);
    Fondo f = new Fondo();
    //f.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    //f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(f);
}

}

public class Fondo extends JPanel{


public Fondo(){

}
@Override
public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
Dimension tamanio = getSize();
ImageIcon imagenFondo = new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/laberinto2.gif"));
g.drawImage(imagenFondo.getImage(),0,0,tamanio.width, tamanio.height, null);
setOpaque(false);
super.paintComponent(g);
}

}
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que escribas el código que tienes para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Listo ya le agregue el código.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este ejemplo traslandándolo a tu código:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    URL url = new URL("<URL to your Animated GIF>");
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Animation");
    f.getContentPane().add(label);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: URL? Venga, entonces haría falta que este alojada en internet y tener conexión a Internet?

Comment: Puedes usar también tu URL local al archivo.

Comment: Te ha funcionado?

Comment: No, simplemente no me sale nada, estoy revisando si no hay otro problema por ahi, en un momento lo notifico, y perdón por abandonar el post, he tenido unos contratiempos.

Comment: Has comprobado que estás introduciendo correctamente la ruta a tu archivo?. Puedes añadir esa sección del código a tu pregunta, así podemos ver si ese es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este codigo con el metodo paintComponent(Graphics g) en tu frame

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Image img = new ImageIcon("ruta del gif").getImage();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```